# How to skip value in config if it doesn't exist?

Tags: config, d, ini

I am writing App, that need to read config at start. Some is not necessary for work.

```
class ParseConfig
{
    string optionalkey;
    //...

    this()
    {
        this.optionalkey = config.getKey("key1");
    }
    //...
}
```

The problem that I need to find way to skip (do not try to find and parse) it if not exists and config. Now App try to parse config and show me error.

I found only one way - to wrap all in try-catch block, and if value can't be found in config in cantch block set it's to null.

What is the best way to do it?

I am using dini for config.

upd: (added example)

```
import std.stdio;
import std.path;
import std.file;
import dini;

void main() 
{
    string confpath = buildPath(getcwd, "config.ini");
    if (!exists(confpath))  throw new Exception("ERROR: config.ini do not exists");
    auto config = Ini.Parse(confpath);
    try
    {
        string optionalkey;
        if(config.getKey("optionalkey"))
        {
            optionalkey = config.getKey("optionalkey");
        }
        writeln(optionalkey); // nothing will shown, becouse exception
    }

    catch( Exception e)
    {
    writeln("Exception! :(");
    writeln(e.msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Catching exception is one way, but it is not perfect (mainly if there will be many cases of optional configs). So better way is test if key exist:

```
class ParseConfig
{
   string optionalkey;
   //...

    this()
    {
        this.optionalkey = config.hasKey("key1") ? config.getKey("key1") : "defaultValue";
    }
    //...
}
```

But ideal would be if dini has overload of getKey method so you can use something like this:

```
this.optionalkey = config.getKey("key1", "defaultValue");
```

But from sources I see it does not have it, but I plan to add it and make a PR.

**UPDATE**

PR: https://github.com/robik/DIni/pull/3

Answer (score 2):

Wrote a pretty advanced ini file wrapper today which supports sections, comments, thread-safety, default values for reading, writing/reading using template values, entry checks etc.

You can get it here:
https://github.com/BaussProjects/baussini

Here is an example usage (example.d from the repo)

```
module main;

import baussini;
import std.stdio : writefln, readln;

void main() {
    string fileName = "test.ini";
    // Thread-safe instance, for a non thread-safe instance replace "true" with "false"
    auto ini = new IniFile!(true)(fileName);
    // Use open() for reading and close() for write. Both can be combined ...
    if (!ini.exists()) {
        ini.addSection("Root");
        // Write way 1
        ini.write!string("Root", "StringValue1", "Hello World!");
        // Write way 2
        ini.getSection("Root").write!int("IntValue1", 9001);
        // Write way 3
        ini.getSection("Root")
            .write!string("StringValue2", "Hello Universe!")
            .write!int("IntValue2", 1000000);
        ini.close();
    }
    else {
        ini.open();
        // Read way 1
        string stringValue1 = ini.read!string("Root", "StringValue1");
        // Read way 2
        int intValue1 = ini.getSection("Root").read!int("IntValue1");
        // Read way 3
        string stringValue2;
        int intValue2;
        ini.getSection("Root")
            .read!string("StringValue2", stringValue2)
            .read!int("IntValue2", intValue2);

        writefln("%s is %s", "stringValue1", stringValue1);
        writefln("%s is %s", "intValue1", intValue1);
        writefln("%s is %s", "stringValue2", stringValue2);
        writefln("%s is %s", "intValue2", intValue2);
        readln();
    }
}
```

In your case you could either use IniFile.hasKey or IniSection().hasKey()
Example:

```
// Check way 1
if (ini.hasKey("Root", "StringValue1")) {
    // The section "Root" has an entry named "StringValue1"
}
// Check way 2
auto section = ini.getSection("Root");
if (section.hasKey("StringValue1")) {
    // The section "Root" has an entry named "StringValue1"
}
```

You could also use default values.

```
string stringValue1 = ini.getSection("Root").read!string("StringValue1", "Default");
// stringValue1 will be "Default" if it doesn't exist within "Root"
```

The default value has to be a string input, but it will always convert the value of it to T.
Ex.

```
int defaultValue = ini.getSection("Root").read!int("IntValue3", "1000");
// defaultValue will be 1000 if it doesn't exist within "Root"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test if a key is present with `hasKey`

```
class ParseConfig
{
    string optionalkey;
    //...

    this()
    {
        if (config.hasKey("key1"))
            this.optionalkey = config.getKey("key1");
    }
    //...
}
```

assuming that we talk about the [same dini](https://github.com/robik/DIni/blob/master/src/dini.d#L92)

Comment: Do you sure that if condition will failure (can't get value) it will continue to work but not rise the exception?

Comment: No i'm not sure at all because i've replied after a quick look at the APIon GH.